# Adding Borders to HTML Table of SQL Query Results

Tags: html, css

Trying to add borders and column headings to a table of results from an SQL query.
The results display fine however there are no headings or borders on the table, so it just looks like a jumble of results.

```
</div>
<div id="section">
<h2>Upcoming Events</h2>
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'c3437691', 'chelsea27', 'c3437691');
?> 

<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM Event"; 
$result=mysqli_query($connection, $query);

echo "<table>";

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['Event_Name']?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Event_Location']?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Event_Date']?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Ticket_Price']?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Ticket_Stock']?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Code is on Pastebin because I had difficulty pasting it here, kept getting formatting errors.

Comment: Where's your <table> tag?

Comment: You never close the `table` element.

Comment: Actually I see now lol.. Idk why you do that but just end your table at the end.

Comment: Read the whole article: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp and remember to not post any passwords in general!

Comment: Have you tried using css?

Comment: There are no headings because you have not coded any headings. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: `<table border="1">` didn't work for you? This is fairly basic HTML, no CSS needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly output your table headers -- simply iterating over results from mysql will not include column names.

After your opening `<table>` but before your `while` loop, add the following:

```
<tr>
<th>Event Name</th>
<th>Event Location</th>
<th>Event Date</th>
<th>Ticket Price</th>
<th>Ticket Stock</th>
</tr>
```

If you want to add borders to the table, you should apply CSS to the table.

Comment: I am aware of this I'm just stuck figuring out where to put them in the code, apologies I wasn't clear enough, quite new to posting here

Comment: Between your `echo "<table>";` and your while loop.